# Нарушение прав доступа при патчинге памяти (в проекции файла на память)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Пишу активатор крэкми. Сразу показываю код, потом объяснения.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

enum {OK, CANT_OPEN, CANT_READ};

unsigned rva_to_va (HANDLE pe_image, unsigned rva)
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header;
    std::memcpy(&dos_header, pe_image, sizeof(dos_header));

    if (dos_header.e_magic != 'ZM')
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to read IMAGE_DOS_HEADER" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Start of PE header must be DWORD-aligned
    if (dos_header.e_lfanew % sizeof(DWORD) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "PE header is not DWORD-aligned" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_headers;
    std::memcpy(&nt_headers,
                 ((char *) pe_image) + dos_header.e_lfanew, sizeof(nt_headers));

    // Check: is our file PE
    if (nt_headers.Signature != 'EP')
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrent PE signature" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Check: is this file PE32
    if (nt_headers.OptionalHeader.Magic != 0x10B)
    {
        std::cout << "This PE is not PE32" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "ImageBase = " << nt_headers.OptionalHeader.ImageBase << std::endl;

    // Calculate RVA to VA
    unsigned validVA = rva - nt_headers.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + (unsigned) pe_image;
    return validVA;
}

int patch (TCHAR* fname)
{
    char first_patch[2]  = {0x90, 0x90};    // NOP NOP
    char second_patch[2] = {0xEB, 0x07};    // JMP 40124C

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile (fname,
                               GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, NULL,
                               NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return CANT_OPEN;

    int SizeFile  = GetFileSize (hFile, NULL);
    HANDLE MhFile = CreateFileMapping (hFile, 0, SEC_IMAGE | PAGE_READWRITE, 0, SizeFile, 0);
    HANDLE View   = MapViewOfFile (MhFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);

    // Получайм виртуальный адрес начала памяти, откуда будем считывать
    unsigned raw = rva_to_va (View, 0x401000);
    std::cout << "raw addr: " << std::hex << raw << std::endl;

    // Читаем байты, которые видны в OllyDbg
    char a, b, c, d;
    std::memcpy (&a, (char *) raw, 1);
    std::memcpy (&b, (char *) raw + 1, 1);
    std::memcpy (&c, (char *) raw + 2, 1);
    std::memcpy (&d, (char *) raw + 7, 1);

    // Печатаем прочитанные четыре байта
    std::cout << "Data on addr " << std::hex << raw << ": ";
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)a << " " << std::hex << (int)b << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)c << " " << std::hex << (int)d << std::endl;

    // Пытаемся пропатчить память возле точки входа
    std::cout << "Patching..." << std::endl;
    raw = rva_to_va (View, 0x401000);
    std::memcpy ((char *) raw, first_patch, 2);

    UnmapViewOfFile (View);
    CloseHandle (hFile);
    CloseHandle (MhFile);
    return OK;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TCHAR* default_fname = "CRACKME.EXE";

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        default_fname = argv[1];
    }

    patch(default_fname);

    std::cout << default_fname << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Действия такие:

1. Отображаю крэкми в пространство процесса
2. Чтобы убедиться в правильности преобразования адресов, печатаю несколько байт
3. Пытаюсь пропатчить память

Вот скрин точки входа в крекми:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выведем несколько байты `6A 00` для первой строчки, `E8` для второй строчки и `A3` для третьей. Код, которые это делает, прокомментирован. Результат работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь хочу пропатчить код, программы выполняется дальше и вылетает с нарушением прав доступа. Почему произошла эта ошибка?

Я открываю файл с правами на чтение и запись, создаю объект mapping со всеми правами доступа (отображаю как образ), представление (view) тоже имеет все права доступа, но при попытке писать в эту память возникает access violation.

Помогите разобраться.